# Assign value to variant parameter

Tags: delphi, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing, delphi-xe

I got code like this in Delphi XE

```
function DoSomething(MyVar : Variant) : boolean;
begin
  MyVar := 'Bar';
  Result := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  foo : string;
begin
  foo := '';
  showmessage(foo); // shows blank ofc
  DoSomething(foo);
  showmessage(foo); // still blank
end;
```

What I am trying to do, make it so the paramater of foo can be set. I tried using the var keyword like

```
DoSomething(var MyVar : Variant)....
```

but that wont compile.

The reason for this, is DoSomething could assign a string or integer to MyVar which is why it's a variant...

Comment: when using a `var` parameter (pass by reference), your `foo : string;` should become `foo : Variant;` just as the compiler tells you.

Answer (score 3):

When I do

```
function Foo(var Bar: variant): boolean;
begin
  Bar := 'beta';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: variant;
begin
  a := 'alpha';
  Foo(a);
  caption := a;
end;
```

the Caption of the form is `beta`. So it compiles for me...

You try to send a `string` as a `var variant` parameter. You need to send a `variant` as a `var variant` parameter, just as the compiler says (`[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(35): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical`)!

But variants are often not the best things to work with (sub-optimal performance, to mention one thing).

You could do something simple like

```
type
  TValType = (vtString, vtInteger);
  TData = record
    ValType: TValType;
    ValStr: string;
    ValInt: integer;
  end;
```

and do

```
function Foo(var Data: TData): boolean;
```

Comment: Why would you want to re-invent the wheel like that. Using variant is fine if you want the type determined by run time